# Isolate ultrasounds with Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

There is any algorithm that I can use with Web Audio Api to isolate ultrasounds?

I've tried 'highpass' filters but I need to isolate sounds that are ONLY ultrasounds (horizontal lines) and ignore noises that are also sounding at lower audible frequencies (vertical lines).

```
var highpass = audioContext.createBiquadFilter();
highpass.type = 'highpass';
highpass.frequency.value = 17500;
highpass.gain.value = -1
```

---

Here's a test with a nice snippet from http://rtoy.github.io/webaudio-hacks/more/filter-design/filter-design.html of how the spectrum of audible noise interferes with filtered ultrasound: (there are 2 canvas, one without the filter and one with the filter https://jsfiddle.net/6gnyhvrk/3

Without filters:
[image]

With 17.500 highpass filter:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A highpass filter is what you want, but there are a few things to consider.  First, the audio context has to have a high enough sample rate.  Second, you have to decide what "ultrasound" means.  Many people can hear frequencies above 15 kHz (as in your example).  A single highpass filter may not have a sharp enough cutoff for you so you'll need to have a more complicated filter setup.

Comment: Thanks Raymond, 15kHz is just for testing porpouses. I edited my question to show what I meant with ignoring noises.

Comment: A high pass filter should do what you want.  If you create a jsfiddle or codepen example, perhaps I can help out a bit.  A single biquad highpass filter may not have a sharp enough cutoff for your application.  You should try it and look at the spectrogram to see if works well enough for you.  If not, you'll need to design a different highpass filter with sharp enough cutoff.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I edited my question with a jsFiddle and  the outputs of highpass

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to say.  The canvas with filters does seem to show some of the lower frequencies removed.  If you want more of the frequencies removed, you'll probably need a more complicated setup.  One possible place to get a better filter (shameless plug): http://rtoy.github.io/webaudio-hacks/more/filter-design/filter-design.html. Choose highpass.  Set passband to 17500, stopband to 16000 (or whatever you want).  Set stopband attenuation to say 50 dB, and passband attenuation(ripple) to 1 dB.  Play around.  Then grab the code snippet at the bottem.

Comment: Thank you Raymond for that tool. I fixed de canvas visual issues and I added the code snippet, and this is the result: https://jsfiddle.net/6gnyhvrk/3/ The algorithm I'm looking for is one capable to detect and rid the ultrasound section of the audible noises (vertical lines)

Comment: Oh, that's a completely different question.  I see that the audible portion of the vertical lines is gone, but the higher frequencies are still there.  I see some bright horizontal lines.  Are those the ones you want to keep?  If so, then a bandpass filter would work.  Unfortunately, I never implemented the bandpass filters, so you'll have to do a combination of lowpass and highpass to keep the frequencies you want.

Comment: Yes! the thing is I need all the ultrasounds not only on speciffic frequency. Could be something like ignore all when there is more than x dB of noise. Thank you for guiding me in the right direction anyway.